# The new line doesn't work when generating xml

Tags: plsql, oracle10g

let's suppose to have the table

```
create table mytable
(val1  number(5),
 val2  varchar2(10));



insert into mytable values (1,'XXX');
```

and asked to generate the following XML

```
<ns1:head>

<ns1:val1>1</val1>

<ns1:val2>XXX</val2>

</ns1:head>
```

It's quite simple by running

```
select xmlelement("head",
       xmlelement("val1",val1).extract('/*'),
       xmlelement("val2",val2).extract('/*')
       ).extract('/*')   
from mytable;
```

and to get

```
<head>

  <val1>1</val1>

  <val2>XXX</val2>

</head>
```

The problem is that if I try to do that way but for getting each node with "ns1:" in front of every tag

```
select xmlelement("ns1:head",
       xmlelement("ns1:val1",val1).extract('/*'),
       xmlelement("ns1:val2",val2).extract('/*')
       ).extract('/*')   
from mytable;
```

I get an ORA-31011: XML parsing failed

Maybe I dont' konw how exactly the .extract('/*') works and in my case the "ns1:" could fails

Oracle version 10g

Thanks in advance!

Mark

Answer (score 0):

What is the purpose of using `extract('/*')`?

Also a namespace prefix must be defined. You can add its declaration in the root element with `xmlattributes`.

```
select xmlelement("ns1:head", xmlattributes('http://www.example.com/ns1' as "xmlns:ns1"),
       xmlelement("ns1:val1",val1),
       xmlelement("ns1:val2",val2)
       )
from mytable;
```

result:

```
<ns1:head xmlns:ns1="http://www.example.com/ns1"><ns1:val1>1</ns1:val1><ns1:val2>XXX</ns1:val2></ns1:head>
```

Update:

`XMLELEMENT` returns and XML object. If you want to get it as a formatted text, you can use `XMLSERIALIZE`.

```
select XMLSERIALIZE(document xmlelement("ns1:head", xmlattributes('http://www.example.com/ns1' as "xmlns:ns1"),
       xmlelement("ns1:val1",val1),
       xmlelement("ns1:val2",val2)
       ) indent)
from mytable;
```

result:

```
<ns1:head xmlns:ns1="http://www.example.com/ns1">
  <ns1:val1>1</ns1:val1>
  <ns1:val2>XXX</ns1:val2>
</ns1:head>
```

Update 2:

as I found out, `indent` instruction does not exist in Oracle 10g. So, if `extract('/*')` worked without namespaces, then adding `xmlattributes` to your original query with namespaces might work. I don't have Oracle 10g to test this.

```sql
    select xmlelement("ns1:head", xmlattributes('http://www.example.com/ns1' as "xmlns:ns1"),
           xmlelement("ns1:val1",val1).extract('/*'),
           xmlelement("ns1:val2",val2).extract('/*')
           ).extract('/*')
    from mytable;
```

Update 3:

Using `extract('/*')` for indenting lines looks like an undocumented feature. On Oracle 12c it doesn't work this way. So, updating Oracle version might break this undocumented behavior.

Comment: I'd like to get every tag/node in a new line and not all the XML along the same line